# Measure how Straight/Smooth the Borders are Rendered in an Image

Tags: noise, python, image-processing, image-restoration

I have two images:

[image]

[image]

I want to measure how straight/smooth the text borders are rendered.

First image is rendered perfectly straight, so it deserves a quality measure `1`. On the other hand, the second image is rendered with a lot of varied curves (rough in a way) that is why it deserves a quality measure less than `1`. How will I measure it using image processing or any Python function or any function written in other languages?

Clarification :

There are font styles that are rendered originally with straight strokes but there are also font styles that are rendered smoothly just like the cursive font styles. What I'm really after is to differentiate the text border surface roughness of the characters by giving it a quality measure.

I want to measure how straight/smooth the text borders are rendered in an image. Inversely, it can also be said that I want to measure how rough the text borders are rendered in an image.

Comment: I have the regret to tell you that the borders are not smooth, because of the many corners of sans-serif fonts. Are you after a measure of rugosity, tortuosity?

Comment: @LaurentDuval - maybe the right term is rugosity (the roughness of the text borders) .  Thanks for correcting.

Comment: by the way, I think the manuscript says "semper", not "lemper".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try a very "tinkery" approach here:

1. Erode the image, so that the black area is shrunk by a fixed radius of pixels from its border (say, 5px).
2. Dilate the resulting image by the same amount
3. measure the amount of difference between original and processed image.

The idea is that something that is a locally convex border doesn't suffer through erosion (it's only shrunk) significantly, and that this erosion can be reverted by dilatation.

Comment: Good, I think mathematical morphology has many tools for that, probably under vaguely shared denominations. Maybe evolutionary segmentation  tools like snakes and level-sets could be useful, as regularity of contours are intrinseque.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, what if the image contains a lot of dirt from the background and white speckles in the foreground? Will it still work?

Comment: Do I have to isolate the largest black component of the character image and do erosion and dilation? Or what if there are white speckles in the foreground character itself, does erosion + dilation and the  difference between the original and resultant image, measures the text border roughness?

Comment: I was thinking of filling the pixel component with white speckles on it, before applying erosion and dilation, so that the difference will just take place at the border of the character. Will it work?

Comment: That would swap 1 and 2, and would probably work.

Comment: Last follow up question, after measuring the amount of difference between original and processed image, what shall I do to normalize the result(Give it a score of 1 if it has straight borders or less than 1 if it isnt)?

Comment: Your design, your specific source images: you need to figure out this yourself. Sounds like a good problem for a bit of making tables, and trying out different things.